# How to hide player when in Shadow using Unity 2D Light System?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, unity-shader-graph

I have been looking for this for a couple of days now and cant find an answer; how can I **hide a player** when they are in the **shadow** when am using Unity **2D Light** System? I know I can choose not to cast light on objects, but when I do it still shows the object in the shadow. What am looking for is **hiding the player** completely when they are in **shadow**, and when the **light hits** them it would **reveal** the player. This effect is in the **game Among Us**, I know that they are using some sort of **shaders** and they didn't have 2D light when they were developing it.

So am assuming this would be a **shader** as well where it would reveal the player when they are in the light and hide them when they are in the shadow. Below are pictures of what I have and what I want it to look like.

**This is what I have in Unity**
[image: Among Us In Unity With 2D Light]

So you can see that the player is **not hidden** in the **shadows**, but rather its **blacked out**.

**But this is what am looking to recreate:**
[image]

You see how the **top half** of the body which is in the **shadow** is hidden while the **bottom half** is **revealed** because its in the **ligh**t? This is the effect that I want to recreate.

Is there some sort of **Shader** or code that can do this? I really been looking for something like this for so long and couldn't find it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure it out, and tbh I wasn't the one who figured it out, I got help from someone on the Unity Discord server. He went into the `Sprite-Lit-Default` and changed some code that accounts for the `luminance`, now I don't know anything about shader programming so I won't be able to explain it much. But he created a `.hlsl` file with the same functionality as the `Sprite-lit-Default` file but added some argument that accounts for `luminance`. Now here are the file content of both the `.shader` file and the `.hlsl` file.

But **YOU NEED TO KEEP BOTH FILES IN THE SAME FOLDER, OTHERWISE IT WONT WORK. ALSO KEEP THE FILE NAMES THE SAME, UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING**

File name `HideInShadow.shader`

```
Shader "Universal Render Pipeline/2D/HideInShadow"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Diffuse", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NormalMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        // Legacy properties. They're here so that materials using this shader can gracefully fallback to the legacy sprite shader.
        [HideInInspector] _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _RendererColor("RendererColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _Flip("Flip", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _AlphaTex("External Alpha", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _EnableExternalAlpha("Enable External Alpha", Float) = 0
    }

    HLSLINCLUDE
    #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
    ENDHLSL

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Universal2D" }
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex CombinedShapeLightVertex
            #pragma fragment CombinedShapeLightFragment
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3 __

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2  uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS  : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color       : COLOR;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                half2   lightingUV  : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/LightingUtility.hlsl"

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MaskTex);
            half4 _MainTex_ST;

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0
            SHAPE_LIGHT(0)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1
            SHAPE_LIGHT(1)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2
            SHAPE_LIGHT(2)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3
            SHAPE_LIGHT(3)
            #endif

            Varyings CombinedShapeLightVertex(Attributes v)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(v.positionOS);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.lightingUV = ComputeNormalizedDeviceCoordinates(o.positionCS);
                o.color = v.color;
                return o;
            }

            #include "CombinedShapeLightSharedHidden.hlsl"

            half4 CombinedShapeLightFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 main = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                half4 mask = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex, sampler_MaskTex, i.uv);

                return CombinedShapeLightShared(main, mask, i.lightingUV);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "NormalsRendering"}
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex NormalsRenderingVertex
            #pragma fragment NormalsRenderingFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 tangent      : TANGENT;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                half3   normalWS        : TEXCOORD1;
                half3   tangentWS       : TEXCOORD2;
                half3   bitangentWS     : TEXCOORD3;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_NormalMap);
            half4 _NormalMap_ST;  // Is this the right way to do this?

            Varyings NormalsRenderingVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _NormalMap);
                o.color = attributes.color;
                o.normalWS = TransformObjectToWorldDir(float3(0, 0, -1));
                o.tangentWS = TransformObjectToWorldDir(attributes.tangent.xyz);
                o.bitangentWS = cross(o.normalWS, o.tangentWS) * attributes.tangent.w;
                return o;
            }

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/NormalsRenderingShared.hlsl"

            half4 NormalsRenderingFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                half3 normalTS = UnpackNormal(SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap, sampler_NormalMap, i.uv));
                return NormalsRenderingShared(mainTex, normalTS, i.tangentWS.xyz, i.bitangentWS.xyz, i.normalWS.xyz);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "UniversalForward" "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex UnlitVertex
            #pragma fragment UnlitFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                float4  color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            Varyings UnlitVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = attributes.color;
                return o;
            }

            float4 UnlitFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                return mainTex;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }

    Fallback "Sprites/Default"
}
```

File name `CombinedShapeLightSharedHidden.hlsl`

```
#if !defined(COMBINED_SHAPE_LIGHT_PASS)
#define COMBINED_SHAPE_LIGHT_PASS

half _HDREmulationScale;
half _UseSceneLighting;
half4 _RendererColor;

half4 CombinedShapeLightShared(half4 color, half4 mask, half2 lightingUV)
{
    if (color.a == 0.0)
        discard;

    color = color * _RendererColor; // This is needed for sprite shape

#if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0
    half4 shapeLight0 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_ShapeLightTexture0, sampler_ShapeLightTexture0, lightingUV);

    if (any(_ShapeLightMaskFilter0))
    {
        half4 processedMask = (1 - _ShapeLightInvertedFilter0) * mask + _ShapeLightInvertedFilter0 * (1 - mask);
        shapeLight0 *= dot(processedMask, _ShapeLightMaskFilter0);
    }

    half4 shapeLight0Modulate = shapeLight0 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors0.x;
    half4 shapeLight0Additive = shapeLight0 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors0.y;
#else
    half4 shapeLight0Modulate = 0;
    half4 shapeLight0Additive = 0;
#endif

#if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1
    half4 shapeLight1 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_ShapeLightTexture1, sampler_ShapeLightTexture1, lightingUV);

    if (any(_ShapeLightMaskFilter1))
    {
        half4 processedMask = (1 - _ShapeLightInvertedFilter1) * mask + _ShapeLightInvertedFilter1 * (1 - mask);
        shapeLight1 *= dot(processedMask, _ShapeLightMaskFilter1);
    }

    half4 shapeLight1Modulate = shapeLight1 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors1.x;
    half4 shapeLight1Additive = shapeLight1 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors1.y;
#else
    half4 shapeLight1Modulate = 0;
    half4 shapeLight1Additive = 0;
#endif

#if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2
    half4 shapeLight2 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_ShapeLightTexture2, sampler_ShapeLightTexture2, lightingUV);

    if (any(_ShapeLightMaskFilter2))
    {
        half4 processedMask = (1 - _ShapeLightInvertedFilter2) * mask + _ShapeLightInvertedFilter2 * (1 - mask);
        shapeLight2 *= dot(processedMask, _ShapeLightMaskFilter2);
    }

    half4 shapeLight2Modulate = shapeLight2 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors2.x;
    half4 shapeLight2Additive = shapeLight2 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors2.y;
#else
    half4 shapeLight2Modulate = 0;
    half4 shapeLight2Additive = 0;
#endif

#if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3
    half4 shapeLight3 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_ShapeLightTexture3, sampler_ShapeLightTexture3, lightingUV);

    if (any(_ShapeLightMaskFilter3))
    {
        half4 processedMask = (1 - _ShapeLightInvertedFilter3) * mask + _ShapeLightInvertedFilter3 * (1 - mask);
        shapeLight3 *= dot(processedMask, _ShapeLightMaskFilter3);
    }

    half4 shapeLight3Modulate = shapeLight3 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors3.x;
    half4 shapeLight3Additive = shapeLight3 * _ShapeLightBlendFactors3.y;
#else
    half4 shapeLight3Modulate = 0;
    half4 shapeLight3Additive = 0;
#endif

    half4 finalOutput;
#if !USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0 && !USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1 && !USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2 && ! USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3
    finalOutput = color;
#else
    half4 finalModulate = shapeLight0Modulate + shapeLight1Modulate + shapeLight2Modulate + shapeLight3Modulate;
    half4 finalAdditve = shapeLight0Additive + shapeLight1Additive + shapeLight2Additive + shapeLight3Additive;
    finalOutput = _HDREmulationScale * (color * finalModulate + finalAdditve);

    half luminance = max(finalModulate.r, max(finalModulate.g, finalModulate.b));
    finalOutput.a = min(luminance * 2, color.a);
#endif

    finalOutput = finalOutput *_UseSceneLighting + (1 - _UseSceneLighting)*color;
    return max(0, finalOutput);
}
#endif
```

The part that he added is that last part where it starts at `half luminance....`

After copying them into your own files, you can then use the `.shader` file to add it to a material and then apply it to the objects you want to disappear in shadows. So if the light hits the object it will appear, but it will appear gradually as the light source gets closer to that object, the only downside to this is there must be a light source in the game so that it can use to calculate the luminance, otherwise the object will just default back to a luminance of 1, meaning completely visible. But, I think if you want to make an object disappear in the shadows then you're most likely using a light source. This is how it looks like:

[image: Gif]

Of course, you play with the light source and the intensity to get the result you want.

If you have any questions I guess you can comment or something and I will help once I see the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is most commonly created by overlaying two cameras, one that renders the players and the other which does not (and has the darkness filter applied). Both are written to textures, after which a full-screen shader determines for which areas to draw in the 'lit' and 'unlit' camera views.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, how would I create that full shader? I know nothing about shaders tbh .

Comment: Also, do shaders not able to detect shadows?